# Unable to fetch data by joining 4 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to fetch data by combining 4 tables but not being able to get desired results.
Following is my truncated table structure.

```
order_line
----------
id
item_id --> item_type_map(item_id) 
amount
quantity

item_type
---------
id --> item_type_map(type_id)    
category_name

item_type_map
-------------
item_id
type_id

international_description
-------------------------
foreign_id --> order_line(item_id)
content
```

Every item (table NOT shown above) belongs to an item_type.
Input to the query will be the list of item_type Ids. And then item wise, I need to select `item_type.category_name, order_line.sum(amount), order_line.sum(quantity), international_description.content`.

I have tried number of combinations but have failed to get the expected results.

For example one of the query that i tried is:-

```
select 
  item_type.category_name, 
  order_line.item_id, 
  international_description.content, 
  sum(order_line.amount) as amount, 
  sum(order_line.quantity) as quantity 
FROM order_line 
INNER JOIN item_type_map ON item_type_map.item_id = order_line.item_id 
INNER JOIN item_type ON item_type.id = order_line.item_id 
INNER JOIN international_description 
               ON international_description.foreign_id = order_line.item_id 
WHERE item_type_map.type_id IN (101, 300) 
GROUP BY order_line.item_id;
```

I have been trying to resolve this issue for almost 2 days now, and really looking forward to some guidance.

The sample data in my table is as follows and i am expecting 3 records in response to above query since there are 3 items that belong to 101 and 300 item_types. But in fact i am getting only 2 results in the response. Please find attached query response below as well.

```
order_line
----------------------------------------------
id  |  item_id  | amount     |    quantity      
----------------------------------------------
'900', '300', '150.0000000000', '1.0000000000'
'1000', '300', '122.0000000000', '1.0000000000'
'1004', '300', '1000.0000000000', '1.0000000000'
'901', '301', '200.0000000000', '1.0000000000'
'1001', '301', '150.0000000000', '1.0000000000'
'1101', '101', '100.0000000000', '1.0000000000'

item_type
----------------------------
id  | description
------------------------------
'101', 'Fees'
'300', 'Adjustments'

item_type_map
--------------------------
item_id | type_id
--------------------------
'101', '101'
'300', '300'
'301', '300'

international_description
-----------------------------
foreing_id  | content
-----------------------------
'101', 'NSF Fee'
'300', 'Adjust - Debit'
'301', 'Adjust - Credit'
```

And the result is:-

```
result
-----------------------------------------------------
category  | item_id  | content  |  amount  | quantity
-----------------------------------------------------
'Fees', '101', 'NSF Fee', '100.0000000000', '1.0000000000'
'Adjustments', '300', 'Adjust - Debit', '1272.0000000000', '3.0000000000'
```

Comment: Is this a typo? `..IN (101,300) and group by...` I mean the and before the group by

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I just corrected the query

Comment: This is just a suggestion, but you might find things like this easier to resolve if, instead of naming your primary key fields simply "id", name them [tableName]id or [tableName]_id.

Comment: change all `inner join` to `left join` and see if you get any resultset!

Comment: 'IN (101, 300)' is valid because those are the 2 item_type ids being passed to the query as an argument. Thanks a lot for pointing that out.

Comment: It would be helpful to see sample data and what the expected results that you're not getting are.

Comment: Hello Bhupesh, i just tried changing INNER JOIN to LEFT JOIN, but still  same result. It returns only one result for a single item_id. My test database has 2 items under item_type 300 and 1 item under item_type 101. So i am expecting the query to return 3 results.

Comment: If you are only getting 1 result, its simply because the data is not joining on the other result.  Look at your data more closely on the fields where you join your tables.  You'll see that it doesnt match, failing one or more joins.

Comment: Hello Paqogomez, i have validated the data and it looks fine. I suspect there is something wrong with my sql query

Comment: Query appears to be structurally fine, provided all the primary keys in between the tables do in fact line up as they should...unless is it possible that some (or maybe all) of the fields are varchar that they could be not matching up because of blank space padding??  If the ID fields are in fact varchar fields, try doing `LTrim(RTrim(yourValue))` on the id's that aren't matching up....

Comment: Hello user2366842, i just verified and all the relevant primary keys are integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The join with `item_type` has wrong criteria. Change it to:

```
INNER JOIN item_type ON item_type.id = item_type_map.type_id
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Amir. That was it.